# SP 2013 How to load PeoplePicker value into promise?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, promises

I'm using the SP PeoplePicker posted in this Microsoft article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/jj713593.aspx

But how can I load the user ID's into a promise? I'm not familiar with the jquery promise method and the explanations found are quite hard to understand.

P.S.: I need the ID's to get passed to CDR Rest Call and posted into a user field list

Code so far:

```
function getUserId(loginName) {

var deferred = $.Deferred();

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
context.load(this.user);
context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this,
        function () { deferred.resolve(this.user); }),
    Function.createDelegate(this,
        function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

return deferred.promise();};
```

**EDIT:**
So this is my PeoplePicker with the promise.
I'm trying to get multiple ID's at once, the standard PplPicker only gives out the first ID

```
    // Run your custom code when the DOM is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the
    // picker will render.
    initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
});

// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

// Query the picker for user information.
function getUserInfo() {

    // Get the people picker object from the page.
    var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

    // Get information about all users.
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var userInfo = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        for (var userProperty in user) {
            userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
        }
    }
    $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

    // Get user keys.
    var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
    $('#userKeys').html(keys);

    // Get the user's ID by using the login name.
    $.when(getUserId(user.key))
    .then(function (result) {
        $('#userId').html(result.get_id());
    });
}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this,
            function () { deferred.resolve(this.user); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the getUserId function as shown below:

```
$.each(users, function (key, user) {
    $.when(getUserId(user.key))
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result.get_id());
    });
});
```

Basically, when the promise is returned, use get_id() method to get the user id. You can pass this ID to the REST call to store it in a People or Group column.

Comment: the code doesn't work, I neither get an error message, nor is the Id posted in console log. I'm really desperated everything I tried so far doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and check what is the value returned to "result" parameter? Also did you check the value of user.key?

Comment: when calling the getUserId function it's giving me the "user is not defined" error

Comment: @Jay, can you share the complete code?

Comment: I edited the code above

Comment: Added outer loop so that you can pass users object to the inner loop. Have edited the answer as well.
$.each(users, function (key, user) {
    $.when(getUserId(user.key))
    .then(function (result) {
        $('#userId').html(result.get_id());
    });
});

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added your code but still there's nothing in the console log. Debugging gives no error tho... Do I have to set a timer maybe?

Comment: It seems that there's no value in "result" when calling getuserid function so it can't get the id